# my radio button can not auto save data with ajax jquery in laravel 8

Tags: html, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

can someone help me with the code I made?, my radio button can't automatically save data with ajax jquery in laravel 8 and I don't get an error message

my controller : Q_AnswersController

```
public function storeAns(Request $request)
    {
        
        $model = new Q_Answer;
        $model->user_id = Auth::id();
        $model->topic_id = $request->topic_id;
        $model->question_id = $request->question_id;
        $model->user_answer = $request->radio_ans;
        $model->answer = $request->answer;
        $topik = $request->topic_id;
        
        $model->save();
               
        return redirect('qanswers/'. $topik);
    }
```

this my route :

```
Route::post('/storeAns',[Q_AnswersController::class, 'storeAns'])->name('storeAns');
```

this is my blade :

```
@foreach ($datas as $key=>$value)
                    <p>{{ $value->question }}</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio_ans" value="{{ $value->a }}"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $value->a }}</label></p>
                      <p><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio_ans" value="{{ $value->b }}"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $value->b }}</label></p>
                        <p><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio_ans" value="{{ $value->c }}"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $value->c }}</label></p>
                        <p><input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio_ans" value="{{ $value->d }}"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $value->d }}</label></p>
                        <p><input type="radio" id="radio5" name="radio_ans" value="{{ $value->e }}"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $value->e }}</label></p>
                        <p><input type="radio" id="radio6" name="radio_ans" value="{{ $value->f }}"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $value->f }}</label></p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="topic_id" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ $value->topic_id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="answer" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ $value->answer }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ $value->id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="question_id" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ $datas->currentPage() }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control" hidden readonly value=" {{ Auth::id(); }} " >
                    @endforeach
```

this is my script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
            var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
            var topic_id = $("#topic_id").val();
            var question_id = $("answer").val();
            var answer = $("answer").val();
            var user_answer = $("radio_ans").val();
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: "{{ url('qanswers.storeAns') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data:{
                    user_id:user_id,
                    topic_id:topic_id,
                    question_id:question_id,
                    answer:answer,
                    user_answer:user_answer
                } ,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#alert').text('Data Inserted Successfully..');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I really appreciate if you guys can help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get radio button value using radio button name in jquery
but this syntax give value undifined

```
var user_answer = $("radio_ans").val();
```

you can try this -

```
var user_answer = $("input[name=radio_ans]:checked").val();
```

Comment: I've tried changing it but it doesn't work

Comment: i found this error : POST 127.0.0.1:8000/qanswers.storeAns 404 (Not Found) – 
indahwati indahwati

Comment: i add this code : data:{
                    _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}',
                    user_id:user_id, ....} and found new error : POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/storeAns 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: i open laravel.log, and showing error : [2022-06-01 01:34:24] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_answer' cannot be null. but i get another value only user_answer i can't get it

Comment: Thank you bro, working for me... i change my route

Answer (score 1):

You are sending user_answer key in your ajax request and in the backend, reading $request->radio_ans instead of $request->user_answer. so change this line:

```
 $model->user_answer = $request->radio_ans;
```

to

```
 $model->user_answer = $request->user_answer;
```

Comment: radio_ans is my name radio button, if i change to username but still not working

Comment: No need to change radio_ans in your JS code. You are sending radio_ans value with the key of user_answer to the backend code. so you need to get user_answer key form `$request`. also you can put `dd($request->all())` at the beginning of storeAns method so you will be able to check the variables passed to the server by using the network tab on your browser dev tools.

Comment: i found this error : POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/qanswers.storeAns 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The `qanswers.storeAns` is wrong. you should send the request to `storeAns ` as you declared in the Route definition. `"{{ url('storeAns') }}"` is correct

Comment: i got this error: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/storeAns 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If you put `dd($request->all())` in `storeAns` method and getting 500 error, it's ok. you just need to take a look at the response coming from the server at network tab on your browser dev tools. or as an alternative, test your endpoint on Postman.

Comment: i open laravel.log, and showing error : [2022-06-01 01:34:24] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_answer' cannot be null. but i get another value only user_answer i can't get it

Comment: thank you bro...working for me now, i change my route